# Efficient way to change background image

Tags: java, swing

I'm looking for an efficient way to let the user set new background images on a JPanel. I have a method created for a custom panel class that is working, but i'm not too sure about it's efficiency. Here is the method:

```
public void setBackgroundImage(String imagePath){
    try{
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
        image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        JLabel backgroundImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        backgroundImage.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600); // temporarily here
        add(backgroundImage);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

First thing I would like to ask is if this will method will create more and more garbage in memory each time it is executed? If so, is there anything I can do to prevent this?

I guess there is a bit I don't yet understand about object creation. Are objects destroyed like local variables are at the end of a method?

Comment: You should probably read up on how Java Garbage collection which is probably beyond the scope of SO post. That being said what a little code I see you should not be concerned with performance.

Comment: @AdamGent Yeah, I probably will sometime soon. Thanks, I was thinking about asking if this little bit of code would even be worth the thought.

Comment: I guess the real question would be, how often are you calling this? If you are just using it every few seconds, fine, but you should not be updating a UI at 30 FPS using this method ;D

Comment: @MattClark Good point, haha. I'm not using this to rapidly update the background like in a game or that. Just a background pic change whenever the user feels like using at something different.